# Castle Windsor Interceptor selectors and hooks

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, interceptor, castle-dynamicproxy

I'm doing some project in Castle Windsor and I have some problems with interceptor hook in config file
I created class that impements `IProxyGenerationHook`:

```
public class LoggingProxyGenerationHook : IProxyGenerationHook
{

    #region IProxyGenerationHook Members

    public void MethodsInspected()
    {
        //throw new Exception("The method or operation is not implemented.");
    }

    public void NonVirtualMemberNotification(Type type, System.Reflection.MemberInfo memberInfo)
    {
        //throw new Exception("The method or operation is not implemented.");
    }

    public bool ShouldInterceptMethod(Type type, System.Reflection.MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        return methodInfo.Name.StartsWith("Save", StringComparison.Ordinal);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

All I want to do is to intercept methods whose name start with "Save" and hook them dynamically in the config file.
Also, in config file I have the following:

```
<component id="LoggingAspect" type="DynamicInterceptor.LoggingAspect, DynamicInterceptor"></component>
<component id="LoggingProxyGenerationHook" type="DynamicInterceptor.LoggingProxyGenerationHook, DynamicInterceptor"></component>
<component id="TestClass1" type="TestClasses.TestClass1, TestClasses">
<interceptors hook ="${LoggingProxyGenerationHook}">
<interceptor>${LoggingAspect}</interceptor>
</interceptors>
</component>
```

I suppose that I'm doing something wrong in config file.
Any ideas?

Comment: so what's NOT working the way you'd expect?

Comment: What do you mean is not filtering? Is not being invoked or its return value is being ignored? Or something else? Be more elaborate if you want someone to help you, don't leave people guessing.

Comment: @nikolavas: That's not a fair thing to say. Krzysztof has spent a lot of his own free time and effort on Castle, even improving Castle documentation a lot.